# Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND calling WooCommerce REST API

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, woocommerce, next.js

I'm creating online store in Next.js in frontend and WooCommerce as Headless CMS for the backend. I have installed woocommerce-api but when I'm getting Error: getaddrinfo. I have tested from postman, there it works fine but not in my server.js code.

.env

```
WORDPRESS_URL=http://woonext.localhost
WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_KEY=KEY
WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_SECRET=KEY
```

server.js

```
const WooCommerceAPI = require('woocommerce-api');
require('dotenv').config();

const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
    url: process.env.WORDPRESS_URL,
    consumerKey: process.env.WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumerSecret: process.env.WOOCOMMERCE_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    wpAPI: true,
    version: 'wc/v3'
});


app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();

    server.get('/products', (req, res) => {
        WooCommerce.get('products', function(err, data, response) {
            console.log(err);
            res.json({ name: 'zain' });
        });
    });

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(port, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
});
```

Error Message:

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND woonext.localhost
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26) {
  errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
  code: 'ENOTFOUND',
  syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
  hostname: 'woonext.localhost'
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Fixed it by running WP site on `localhost:8888`